# TransportError (429) 'Data too large' when loading JSON docs to ElasticSearch

Tags: python, elasticsearch, asynchronous

I have a process running in Python 3.7 that loads JSON files, gathers file rows into chunks in async queues, and incrementally posts chunks to ElasticSearch for indexing.

Chunking is meant to avoid overloading the ElasticSearch connection.

```
def load_files_to_queue(file_queue, incomplete_files, doc_queue, index):
    logger.info("Initializing load files to queue")
    while True:
        try:
            current_file = file_queue.get(False)
            logger.info("Loading {} into queue.".format(current_file))
            iteration_counter = 0
            with open(current_file) as loaded_file:
                iterator = json_iterator(loaded_file)
                current_type = "doctype"
                chunk = []
                for row in iterator:
                    # Every so often check the queue size
                    iteration_counter += 1
                    if iteration_counter > 5000:
                        # If it gets too big, pause until it has gone
                        # down a bunch.
                        if doc_queue.qsize() > 30:
                            logger.info(
                                "Doc queue at {}, pausing until smaller.".format(
                                    doc_queue.qsize()
                                )
                            )
                            while doc_queue.qsize() > 10:
                                time.sleep(0.5)
                        iteration_counter = 0

                    for transformed in transform_single_doc(current_type, row, index):
                        if transformed:
                            chunk.append(transformed)
                    # NOTE: Send messages in chunks in stead of single rows so that queue
                    # has less frequent locking
                    if len(chunk) >= DOC_QUEUE_CHUNK_SIZE:
                        doc_queue.put(chunk)
                        chunk = []
                if chunk:
                    doc_queue.put(chunk)
            incomplete_files.remove(current_file)
            logger.info("Finished loading {} into queue.".format(current_file))
            logger.info("There are {} files left to load.".format(file_queue.qsize()))
        except Empty:
            break

def bulk_load_from_queue(file_queue, incomplete_files, doc_queue, chunk_size=500):
    """
    Represents a single worker thread loading docs into ES
    """
    logger.info("Initialize bulk doc loader {}".format(threading.current_thread()))
    conn = Elasticsearch(settings.ELASTICSEARCH, timeout=180)
    dequeue_results(
        streaming_bulk(
            conn,
            load_docs_from_queue(file_queue, incomplete_files, doc_queue),
            max_retries=2,
            initial_backoff=10,
            chunk_size=chunk_size,
            yield_ok=False,
            raise_on_exception=True,
            raise_on_error=True,
        )
    )
    logger.info("Shutting down doc loader {}".format(threading.current_thread()))
```

Occasionally an error like this would happen in `bulk_load_from_queue`, which I interpret to mean the chunk was too large.

```
TransportError(429, 'circuit_breaking_exception', '[parent] Data too large, data for [<http_request>] would be [1024404322/976.9mb], which is larger than the limit of [1011774259/964.9mb], real usage: [1013836880/966.8mb], new bytes reserved: [10567442/10mb], usages [request=32880/32.1kb, fielddata=7440/7.2kb, in_flight_requests=164031664/156.4mb, accounting=46679308/44.5mb]')
```

Re-running usually resolved this, but the error has become too frequent. So I looked to enforce a chunk size limit in `load_files_to_queue` like so:

```
                    for transformed in transform_single_doc(current_type, row, index):
                        if transformed:
                            chunk_size = chunk_size + sys.getsizeof(transformed)
                            chunk.append(transformed)
                    # NOTE: Send messages in chunks in stead of single rows so that queue
                    # has less frequent locking
                    if (
                        chunk_size >= DOC_QUEUE_CHUNK_SIZE
                        or len(chunk) >= DOC_QUEUE_CHUNK_LEN
                    ):
                        doc_queue.put(chunk)
                        chunk = []
                        chunk_size = 0
                if len(chunk) > 0:
                    doc_queue.put(chunk)
```

This results in a handful of these errors towards the end of processing:

```
ConnectionResetError
[Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

and then:

```
EOFError multiprocessing.connection in _recv
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

basically this means your request to Elasticsearch was too large for it to handle, so you could try reducing the chunk size

alternatively, look at using the _bulk api, there are helpers in the python clients which should take most of the pain away for this

Comment: yes. Dialing down the chunk_size in `bulk_load_from_queue` seems to have resolved the ElasticSearch errors.

Comment: awesome to hear! also just to clarify, it's Elasticsearch, not ElasticSearch :)

Answer (score 0):

We are encountering this again in our QA environment @brenden. do you suggest to further reduce the chunk size ? currently being passed as 200.

```
for worker in range(doc_worker_count):
    job = doc_pool.apply_async(
        bulk_load_from_queue,
        args=(file_queue, incomplete_files, doc_queue, 200),
        error_callback=error_callback,
    )
    jobs.append(job)
```